# jquery not defined on some browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Need one help. 
I have a web application on struts and jQuery.

Sometimes, I get an issue that on some specific user's browsers(mostly FireFox), I get 'jQuery not defined' error. However, the application works fine anywhere else.

I came across this issue and identified the error using Firebug console, when the application's users complained about application not working in their FireFox browsers.

But the application works fine anywhere else including FireFox.

I've included the jQuery scripts file right at the start in the scripts tag

Please help.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<jsp:include page="Header.jsp" flush="true"></jsp:include>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/diceCommonUtilities.js?<%=Reset.iSOLVERSION_NUMBER%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/prototype.js?<%=Reset.iSOLVERSION_NUMBER%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Utilities.js?<%=Reset.iSOLVERSION_NUMBER%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Quickcreate.js?<%=Reset.iSOLVERSION_NUMBER%>"></script>
```

And in Header.jsp, I include all jQuery scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.min.js?<%=Reset.iSOLVERSION_NUMBER%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.js?<%=Reset.iSOLVERSION_NUMBER%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.datePicker.js?<%=Reset.iSOLVERSION_NUMBER%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.bgiframe.pack.js?<%=Reset.iSOLVERSION_NUMBER%>" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.blockUI.js?<%=Reset.iSOLVERSION_NUMBER%>"></script>
```

Comment: Please post the part of HTML where you include the jQuery JS files.

Comment: Check if jquery script was successfully loaded with Firebug Net console

Comment: I checked. It was loaded.

Comment: What exactly the error is? What will `console.log($(document))` display?

Comment: Maybe a conflict with prototype.js redefining `$` ? Check [this page](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/).

Comment: Thanks.
It might be conflicting with prototype.js or any other js.

I removed the conflicts. It is working fine.